# What is the main difference between lemon and lime?

Tags: lemon, lime

Lemons and limes are both very acidic but have slightly different flavors and scents.

Answer (score 1):

you answered your own question: "slightly different flavour and scent"

The main difference, at least for me, is that lime do not have as much juice as lemon.

Comment: Wouldn't this have been better as a comment?